# Angular material tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material

I'm on a situation where I'm using tabs from angular-material : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

Let's suppose I have a tabs with 2 cols. From the second cols I call a modal in order to submit actions. when I close the modal, I use $route.reload to refresh my view. The problem is that after $route.reload , it will come back to the first col and not remain in the second call where I was.

Is there a hack to fix this situation ?

Comment: can you illustrate or take a screenshot? the situation is hard to imagine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config:

```
$routeProvider.when('/mypage/tab2', {
            templateUrl: '/mypage/tab2data.html',
            controller: 'pageCtrl',
            title: 'Add New Courses'
            }
        });
```

In your material tab:

```
<md-tab label="tab1e" ng-click="tab2()"></md-tab>
```

Now in your controller, define the function:

```
$scope.tab2 = function(){
    $location.path('/mypage/tab2');
}
```

Now when you click your `tab2`, url will change, you'll able to bookmark it, so it won't redirect to default tab.